# JSON response with varying nesting pattern from 3rd-party API

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net5

I get a third-party API response which has several nested properties:

Variation 1:

```
{
    "Property1": {
        "Property2A": {
            "Key1": "1",
            "Key2": "2",
            "Key3": "3"
        },
        "Property2B": {
            "Property3": {
                "Key4": "A",
                "Key5": "B",
                "Key6": "C",
                "Property4": {
                    "Property5": {
                        "Property6": [
                            {
                                "Key7": "1",
                                "Property7A": {
                                    "X": "1"
                                },
                                "Property7B": {
                                    "X": "2"
                                },
                                "Property7C": {
                                    "X": "3"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "Property7D": {
                                    "X": "INeedThisString"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I only need the value "**INeedThisString**".

I am able to reach the value of property `"X": "INeedThisString"` by a suitable model structure (generated by mapping the model over the Json-File) and with the following declarations:

```
Rootobject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(MyJsonString);
string result = obj.Property1.Property2B.Property3.Property4.Property5.Property6[1].Property7D.X;
```

**Here's my problem**:

The API sometimes issues a variation of this architecture which has -as the only difference- **Property3 declared as an array** such as:

Variation 2:

```
{
    "Property1": {
        "Property2A": {
            "Key1": "1",
            "Key2": "2",
            "Key3": "3"
        },
        "Property2B": {
            "Property3": [ //<-----
                    {
                    "Key4": "A",
                    "Key5": "B",
                    "Key6": "C",
                    "Property4": {
                        "Property5": {
                            "Property6": [
                                {
                                    "Key7": "1",
                                    "Property7A": {
                                        "X": "1"
                                    },
                                    "Property7B": {
                                        "X": "2"
                                    },
                                    "Property7C": {
                                        "X": "3"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "Property7D": {
                                        "X": "INeedThisString"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]  //<-----
        }
    }
}
```

`//<-----`: added 2x for illustration purposes.

Obviously, variation 1 and my current model structure do not declare `Property3` as an array.

**Question:**

What's an elegant approach to solve this *without touching the Json (deletions/replacements) in pre-processing*?

Should I implement an alternative set of models and switch between those two model-sets via an error-function? Please note that the keys within properties `7A`-`7D` are all the same: `"X"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current working solution covers an alternative set of classes needed for parsing, resulting from mapping Variant 2 of the Json response.

All classes are decorated by Json headers [JsonProperty("actual-string-shown-in-Json")] via using directive `using Newtonsoft.Json`.

The two alternative `JsonConvert` functions are placed within a try-catch statement:

```
string result;
try
{
Rootobject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(MyJsonString);
result = obj.Property1.Property2B.Property3.Property4.Property5.Property6[1].Property7D.X;
}

catch
{
AltRootobject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AltRootobject>(MyJsonString);
result = obj.AltProperty1.AltProperty.AltProperty[0].AltProperty.AltProperty5.AltProperty6[1].AltProperty7D.AltX;
}
```